# Python regex substitute syntax skip lines with certain criteria

Tags: python, regex, substitution, python-re

I would like to make substitutions within a string only if the line meets certain criteria.

```
text_old = """
with some text 
some text as(
-- from text some text
with select text some other text
-- with text
from text
"""
```

where my substitutions are -

```
replacements = [
    ('with ','with \n'),
    ('as\n ','as'), 
    ('as\(','as (') 
        ]
for old, new in replacements:
    text_new = re.sub(old,new,text_old,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

And I want to skip the substitution if the line starts with `--` . So the `from` and `with` replacements are skipped here -

```
-- from text some text
-- with text
```

Comment: Add `(?<!^--.*)` to each regex and use the PyPi `regex` module, not `re`. Just `pip install regex` and then `import regex as re` and use your `re.sub`...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew add the syntax within ```replacements```?

Comment: See [the Python demo](https://tio.run/##dZDBTsMwDIbvfgrTSxKU7sINMSGEJsQFJDhSQNlw10ptUiVGG09fkpSOHiAXO/6/33YyfHHj7MU4tv3gPKOnPR3RhJgAMB353XUfuMaiKODQcoPB9YRJQPhNTZBQllh710@Fk/Rjoo52vJAcN@QnIPoyky@nDpAGgqehMzvqyXKIS7wAxiO9kNdXZ29luTpX1TabhRY5VlYo/RdlQmUTZUIE8B9CZgClUAiv0@stHeLg@SOgdh5j1JjqrcXlgpe568LlaRU@tzLxsaBnRded2Yd1VO/vHh6fNrc3zxsFMPjWspwhNY7f).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I do receive an error ```error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern```, could this be due to spacing? if  ``` --```  vs ```--```, although I don't believe so

Comment: I wrote how to do that: 1) `pip install regex` in the terminal/console to install the PyPi regex module, then 2) use the code from the link. *Use the PyPi `regex` module, not `re`.*

Comment: ok excellent, thank you did not see the difference between ```regex``` and ```re```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem with pure regex with the PyPi `regex` module. Go to console/terminal and run the `pip install regex` command. This will allow you to `import regex` in your script and all that remains to do is add `(?<!^--.*)` to each regex:

```py
replacements = [
    (r'(?<!^--.*)\bwith ','with \n'),
    (r'(?<!^--.*)\bas\n ','as'), 
    (r'(?<!^--.*)\bas\(','as (') 
]
```

You also need to use `re.M` (`regex.M`) flag to make sure `^` matches all line start positions and not just a start of the whole string.
See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##dZDBbsMgDIbvfgovF6AivfQ2req5hz3B0lW0c5pICURA1U7au2eGLF0OGwcw/r/fNgyfsXF2M45tPzgf0dOF7mgCBwCR7vHoug/cYlEUcGtjg8H1hElA@A1NkFCWWHvXT4mH9GOijs5xIbnYkJ8A9mUmXx4VIDUET0NnztSTjYGHeAPkJb2Qu5en97Jcr1R1ymahRT4rK5T@izKhsokygQH8h5AZQCkUwmF6vaUbN54/AmrnkU@NKd9aXA74nKsuXJ7W4XqSieeEnhVdd@YStqzuv3h7VQCDb22UM6DG8Rs):

```py
import regex as re

text_old = """
with some text 
some text as(
-- from text some text
with select text some other text
-- with text
from text
"""

replacements = [
    (r'(?<!^--.*)\bwith ','with \n'),
    (r'(?<!^--.*)\bas\n ','as'), 
    (r'(?<!^--.*)\bas\(','as (') 
]
text_new = text_old
for old, new in replacements:
    text_new = re.sub(old,new,text_new,flags=re.I|re.M)

print(text_new)
```

Output:

```py
with 
some text 
some text as (
-- from text some text
with 
select text some other text
-- with text
from text
```

Comment: for case insensitive ```--``` skip, would ```(?i)``` be used within ```r'(?<!^--.*)```?

Comment: something like ```-- WITH text``` indents from the first instance

Comment: @paranormaldist If you need to use case insensitive search for selected items only, you can use `(?i)` at the start of the pattern, `r'(?i)(?<!^--.*)\bwith '`, for example.

Comment: i'm having trouble with this one line ```-- WITH text``` it doesn't skip regardless of case insensitive or not @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @paranormaldist I see, these are lines in a multiline document, so you need `regex.M` flag, too, use `flags=regex.I | regex.M`

Comment: oh right, yes perfect thank you for following up